CORS (Cross Origin Resource Sharing) in web
I am pretty much new to web development.
And recently I came across a term called CORS (Cross Origin Resource Sharing).
What I understand is that:
Suppose I visit a site called www.example.com in my browser. The served page has a JavaScript embedded in it. If the embedded JavaScript is sending a request to another site which is in a different domain (lets say: abc.com), is this request blocked by the browser?
OR the request is sent to abc.com; but abc.com server sends a 'NO' to the browser; then the browser says to the user that the request to abc.com is not allowed.
I read through several answers and baffled which of the above two statement is correct.
If the second statement is correct, then browser has nothing to do with CORS; because it still sends the cross origin request to the other domain web server. So CORS responsibility lies 100% with the web server.
And also I understand that backend servers identifies the domain from origin http header field. So CORS comes into picture whenever if there are frontend tools to communicate with the server (like: browsers) where headers are populated by the tools.
If the communication happens via only API calls (say: using a programming language library), CORS risk is not at all there.
Say for example: If I use CURL, the origin http header field is not populated; So the server can not identify from where the request comes from. And hence CORS is nowhere in this communication. Am I correct here?

you might check https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS CORS also relies on a mechanism by which browsers make a "preflight" request to the server hosting the cross-origin resource

The browser enforces the CORS rules to help protect its users.  Native requests don't have CORS rules.  The browser sends an  request (pre-flight check) to the server and the server responds with a list of allowed origins.  The server never sees the origin header.  The browser already knows the origin and checks if it's allowed or not.  If it's allowed the request is sent.  If it's not in the allowed list, or the server doesn't respond to  request at all, it is not sent.  The rules are fairly complicated, but "simple" requests do not require pre-flight.

Great explanation, thanks!!

Cross-origin restrictions are fully managed by a browser. This means if you build a HTTP client on the terminal it can completely ignore CORS.
However, the server is a component. The way CORS effectively works is that the browser asks the server: "Do you allow me to make this request". If the server says 'no' the client will block the request. There's some additional nuance with GET requests, but the summary is that the server informs the browser what's allowed, and the browser enforces that policy.
If the server does not have a policy, the default is to reject requests that require CORS headers.

It's worth pointing out that browsers does not by default block all CORS requests; only non-simple ones. For simple requests, the browser only asks the server: "Can I share your response with the client (i.e. the issuer of the request)?".
